# Obtain a Class reference to Vector.<T>

Tags: actionscript-3

Is it possible to obtain a `Class` reference to a `Vector.<T>`? I tried the following code:

```
var cls : Class = Vector.<int>;
```

But it fails with a coercion error, presumably because `Vector.<T>` is also a global function. Is there a simple way around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: **Best solution**:

```
var vectorIntDefinition:Class = Vector.<int> as Class;
```

---

I don't know if you call this solution simple as you need some "reflection magic" but it works:

```
var vectorIntClassName:String = getQualifiedClassName(Vector) + ".<" + getQualifiedClassName(int) + ">";
var vectorIntDefinition:Class = getDefinitionByName(vectorIntClassName) as Class;
```

Hint: If you use that more than once you could create a little helper method.

**Edit: Look at my 2nd comment.**

Comment: OK, theres a shorter way (but also relys on reflection): 
     var vectorIntDefinition:Class = getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(Vector.<int>)) as Class;

Comment: Arg, just write: `var vectorIntDefinition:Class = Vector.<int> as Class;`

Comment: Perfect. You should move that last comment to your answer as that's really the best way to go.

Comment: I think Warappa is showing in his second example how you might do it if you need the Class but you don't know the generic type at compile-time.  To me, option #1 looks good when you know exactly what you want.  Option #2 is for when you need to do some neat factory magic... like VectorFactory.createMeAVector(typeToCreate);

Comment: @Brian - Agreed, but the question was related to obtaining a compile-time reference so highlighting that answer makes sense.